# Turn-off automatic repartitioning in Spark 2

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I recently upgraded my code from Spark 1.6 to Spark 2.1

I wrote some code for Spark 1.6 to

1. repartition a data frame,
2. store the data frame as a parquet file and
3. re-load the data frame from the parquet file.

So far the **number of partitions was always constant** throughout all these operations.

Since I have upgraded to Spark 2.1, I can see that the data is stored using the specified number of partitions (there are as many part-files as partitions specified). However, when I **read** the parquet file, the number of partitions is suddenly a completely different one.

Why is this and how can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: When you re-load it from disk, it would create a single partition for each file system block. So it could be that some of your output files are larger than a block. If the format you use is splittable. Are they compressed?

Comment: Yes, they are compressed; but the number of partitions is smaller than the specified number. I have been been experimenting with the repartition function and I am not sure that it works properly in Spark 2. The elements in the partitions when doing `df.rdd.map(row => (row.getAs[Long](pCol), row)).partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))`  are not the same compared to when I do `df.repartition(n, col(pCol))`...

Comment: Apparently when running Spark with local[X] as master, the number of partitions equals X and not the number of partitions when it was stored.